# Is the result of the value computation of an atomic object unspecified?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, atomic

[intro.races] p14 says:

> The value of an atomic object M, as determined by evaluation B, shall be the value stored by **some side effect A that modifies M**, where B does not happen before A.

"some side effect A" means possibly a random value in the modification order, whis is confirmed by this https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/6501. So, consider this example:

```cpp
std::atomic<int> v{0};
auto c = [](){v.store(1,std::memory_order::release); return 1;}();
auto c2 = [](){v.store(2,std::memory_order::release); return 2;}();

int main(){
   auto r = v.load(std::memory_order::acquire); // #1
}
```

First, we can be sure that `#1` does not happen before these modifications. So, what is the result of the value computation at `#1`? Is it the latest value in the modification order, or Can it be `0`, `1`, or `2`, either of them is possible, which is unspecified? In this example, The [implementations](https://godbolt.org/z/x9veWqzEM) always say the result is `2`, which results even though also obeys the rule, however, I wonder whether this result is determined? Or, it is just an unspecified behavior.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#18

Comment: @T.C. This rule does not explain what I am asking in the question. If `#1` reads `0`, it does not violate [intro.races] p18

Comment: This has nothing to do with atomics, atomics are odd there

Comment: Aren't global-scope initializers are sequenced-before the body of `main`?  They happen in the main thread, so both stores happen-before the load.  (As 273K points out, it's safe for main to read non-`atomic` globals with non-constant initializers.)  It could load either `1` or `2` depending on the implementation detail of what order it did them, but it can't load `0` because of the write-read coherence rule.

Comment: @PeterCordes I asked in the linked PR, and the answer is the result is guaranteed to be `2`. *but it can't load 0 because of the write-read coherence rule* I don't know why it cannot be `0`.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong about `1` being possible.  Turns out non-local initializers are ordered within the same TU when they're not template instantiations.  *[static global variables initialization order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54159044)*.  (And they're all ordered before main, so `c`'s initializer happens-before `c2`'s initializer, and that happens-before main's load.

Comment: @PeterCordes   I was about to start write something saying exactly that.   I suggest you turn your observations into  an answer.  Essentially - it is guaranteed that initialisation of `v`, `c`, and `c2` (all being in one translation unit) are initialised in order, and their side effects (calling the lambda functions) completed, before `main()` is called.    [The use of atomics doesn't actually change anything either].

Comment: @Peter: Seems like a duplicate to me; the thing the OP seemed to be missing was that the c and c2 initializers are indeed sequenced before main, and thus happen-before it, so I found a duplicate that looks appropriate for that.  (It doesn't involve atomics, because write-read coherence and other guarantees from atomics make them work as expected in single-threaded code even with relaxed.  And I think the OP knows that?  Or maybe that's the part they're not understanding.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I wonder about the meaning of [intro.race] p18, it seems that p18 guarantees the read value should be `2`, however, I didn't read that meaning in p18.

Comment: The load is a value computation on `v`.  The last write (of `2`) is a side-effect on `v` which happens-before the value computation.  So it sees `2` or any *later* value in the modification order.  But there aren't any later modifications so the only possibility is `2`.  This rule is how C++ guarantees that `shared = 2; tmp = shared;` reads `2` if there are no other threads doing anything to it, regardless of what earlier values exist in its modification order.

Comment: @PeterCordes However, [intro.races] p14 says the read value can be some "unspecified" value in the modification order. Aren't `0`, `1`, and `2` these values?

Comment: @PeterCordes   Fair enough.

Comment: @xmh0511 You're ignoring the note directly below [intro.races] p14: *[Note 14: The set of such side effects is also restricted by the rest of the rules described here, and in particular, by the coherence requirements below. — end note]*.  Without the coherence rules, yes, atomics would be broken within a single thread.  That's why the standard has those rules, and why p14 makes it explicit that it's *not* overriding those later rules.

Comment: @PeterCordes Could you specifically say which extra rule is relevant here?

Comment: Dude.  Write-read coherence, [intro.races] p18 (https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#18), the one people have repeatedly told you was what guaranteed this.  I even explained in my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471430/is-the-result-of-the-value-computation-of-an-atomic-object-unspecified?noredirect=1#comment136578277_77471430) how it guarantees it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. However, the "or" does not require the value computation `B` must read `Y`, isn't it? IMO, "or" is an option, that is, `B` can read `X` or `Y`, this is my confusion about that rule. Or, do you mean, in this case, only the evaluation of storing `2` happens before `#1`?

Comment: *or from a side effect Y that follows X in the modification order of M.* - Like I already explained, there is no possible `Y`.  If there aren't any other threads, no later writes happen after the `v=2` store.  (p15 write-write coherence guarantees that modification order is consistent with the sequencing of writes within this single thread.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant, consider the side effect of writing `1` is that `X`, the `Y` is the side effect of writing `2`, p18 means the value computation `B` can read `X` or `Y`, which is `1` or `2`, it didn't say `B` must read `2`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I found you said *(And they're all ordered before main, so c's initializer happens-before c2's initializer, and that happens-before main's load.* According to [basic.start.dynamic], `c` is sequence before `c2`, which both is sequence before the first statement of main(if the initialization is not deferred), which means `c` and `c2` can both happens before the value computation.

Comment: p18 applies to the store of 1, meaning it can see that or later.  p18 *also* applies to the store of `2`, meaning it can see that or later.  There is no later. It can only see the `2`.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is, if I say the result of the value computation at `#1` is `1`, it still didn't violate p18, isn't it? So, that is why I say I cannot understand why `2` is guaranteed by p18.

Comment: I already explained this in my last comment.  If you loaded `1`, you *would* violate p18 wrt. the store of `2` and the load.  The store of `2` happens-before the load, so p18 guarantees that it or a later value is loaded.  `1` is not a later value in the modification-order (by p15), it's an *earlier* value.  The p18 rule applies separately between each store and each later load.  The load value you see has to satisfy *all* the requirements imposed, not just one; that's the same mistake you were making earlier by only looking at p14 without considering p15-p18.

Comment: Added [Does memory\_order\_relaxed respect data dependencies within the same thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69725529) as a duplicate since it seems that's the part you're getting hung up on.  The rules for static initializers make it equivalent to  `v = 1; v = 2; tmp = v;` with ops weaker than seq_cst, and you're asking whether `tmp = v` can load `1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, assume there is another thread that will modify `v` as `3`(i.e the third side effect) in my original example, and assume the value computation at `#1` does not happen before the third side effect(i.e. `3`), in this case, the result of `r` can be `2` or `3`, which is unspecified, right?

Comment: So the `v=3` is unordered wrt. `v=2` since it's in another thread and you didn't mention any happens-before.  Then yes, either one could have happened later, becoming the last value in the mod order.  That's the value `#1` will see, since it happens after both stores.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, I see. I try to talk about my understanding of your explanation, please confirm whether I understand them correctly. In my original example, assuming `#1` reads the value stored by `c`, for this single side effect the rule in intro.races#18 is satisfied, however, there is another side effect `c2`, which also needs to undergo intro.races#18, since the read side effect in `c` is prior that of `c2` in the modification order, so **the rule is violated** when applying to `c2`. If `#1` reads `c2`, then intro.races#18 is also satisfies when applying to `c` since `c2` is that `Y`.

Comment: @PeterCordes For the case after introducing `v = 3`, `X` in intro.races#18 is `v = 2` and `Y` is `v = 3` if `v = 3` is after `v=2` in the mod order, the rule permits the value computation at `#1` can either read `v=2` or `v=3`, which either can make the rule be satisfied, right?

Comment: first comment: yes, that's correctly re-stating the explanation discussed earlier.  second comment: No.  You said the read is after *both* writes.  The situation where `X` is `v=2` and `Y` is `v=3` would apply if the read was unsynchronized with the `v=3` write so it could read `v` before `3` became part of its modification order.  If the read happens after both writes, it has to see whichever one was later in the mod order, for the same reason it sees `c2` not `c` in the other example.

Comment: We can read 2 or 3 because the `v=3` could come before `v=2` in the mod order. 
 The writes are unsynced so [p15](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#15) write-write coherence doesn't apply between the two writes, unlike between c and c2 which are sequenced.  So the only situation (under the conditions you've specified) where #1 reads `3` is where the long-term final value of `v` is `3`, after the dust settles, which is the same thing as saying that it ended up later in the modification order than `2`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the second comment is another question and the comment is too short to express the whole thought, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77513283/is-the-read-value-unspecified-in-this-case-where-one-happens-before-the-vaue-com